# Does reputation earned from a now deleted post count towards the yearling badge?

Tags: support, reputation, badges

For example if I received 100 rep from answering a question, and that question was removed for some reason, does that reputation count towards a yearling badge?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way would be if the question was deleted after the year ended. Badges (except for tag badges) are not removed once received.

If you did end up in the situation that you have the badge without the necessary rep for that year, to get the next year's badge you'd need to earn that missing 100 rep as well as the 200 rep for that years' badge.

One other way to get the badge with a deleted post would be if [the rep came from an answer that scored 3 or more that was visible for more than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327540/conditions-for-keeping-reputation-in-case-of-post-deletion) as in that case the rep is not removed.

Comment: thank you, but I'm going to earn the badge this year, and some reputation removed before earning badge, now my question is if those removed reputation counts for this year yearling badge or not? And the question is not about removing earned badges.

Comment: @NimaDerakhshanjan You don't need to earn the reputation within the year you are getting the yearling badge for. You can earn the reputation in earlier or later years and still be awarded the badge. The badge will even be awarded later, if you get the reputation after the end of your year. For example, I recently [earned the yearling badge on SU 4 times in 3 days](https://superuser.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=340927), due to providing a [popular answer](https://superuser.com/a/1432814/340927) that gave me enough reputation for those earlier years.